# Is there a way to execute arbitrary code in C preprocessor?

Tags: c, gcc, lisp

Consider this program:

```
#define MACRO                                   \
    srand(time(NULL));                          \
    if (rand() % 2)                             \
        printf("A");                            \
    else                                        \
        printf("B");

int main() {
    MACRO;
}
```

It is the equivalent of the following macro-expanded program:

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    if (rand() % 2)
        printf("A");
    else
        printf("B");
}
```

Obviously, the `if` statement is executed in runtime and not in macro-expansion phase. If the `if` statement was executed in compile time and if there was syntax quoting (as in Lisp), we could get programs A and A' with (almost) equal probability. Where A:

```
int main() {
    printf("A");
}
```

and A':

```
int main() {
    printf("B");
}
```

Is there a way to make GCC emit A or A' with regard to a condition evaluated in compile time?

Comment: Are you asking if a preprocessor can generate random numbers? No, but you can pass the output of `/dev/urandom` to the compiler with `-D` and use the `#if` preprocessor directive.

Comment: How about `gcc -DMACRO=printf("A"); test.c` or `gcc -DMACRO=printf("B"); test.c`

Comment: When the preprocessor expands `MACRO;` it creates an empty statement `srand ... ("B");;` because, unusually, your macro terminates with a semicolon. Just saying ... there is no problem with empty statements.

Comment: Thank you @EugeneSh.and @cleblanc. With `-D` option we just supply the macro from outside of the codebase, right? It won't make preprocessor do any work different then it would do if we put the macro within the codebase.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianGibbons, that was a typo. Although, when I looked at the description of `macro` tag and it probably isn't the best possible tag that I could put here. :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. You made me realize that OP can actually achieve what he wants. Nice to know about `/dev/random`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to execute arbitrary code in C preprocessor?

No, and this was an intentional design decision by the authors of the original (1989) C standard.  They were familiar with much more powerful macro systems (e.g. from Lisp, which does allow for arbitrary computation at compile time) and they thought those made it too hard to understand what an unfamiliar program means.

It is not clear to me why you want to make a random choice at compile time.  If you explain your larger goals we may be able to be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "Why?". A colleague of mine asked me: "How horrible is compiling arbitrary C code submitted to a server?". The answer that I had at the moment was "Provided that you can write arbitrary code in macros, it's infinitely horrible." Then I tried to write some malicious code in macros to check my answer. I quickly realized that it's actually not that straight forward and that I was too Lisp-thinking at the moment.

Comment: Actually, you can execute arbitrary code in CPP. [BoostPP](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/AppendixA-AnIntroductiontoPreprocessorMetaprogramming.html) implements control structures, data types, and operations.

Comment: @okovko That doesn't qualify as "arbitrary code execution" for two reasons: it can't do arbitrary I/O, and it is subject to fixed upper limits on how many times you can iterate or recurse, making some algorithms unimplementable.

Comment: @zwol The same limitation exists for any program. I/O is file based, which is inconvenient, but still I/O.

Comment: @okovko No, this is qualitatively different.  In CS-theoretic terms, I am ~95% certain the preprocessor can _at best_ only compute [primitive recursive](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitiveRecursiveFunction.html) functions, which means for instance it is impossible to implement [the Ackermann function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AckermannFunction.html)

Comment: No, you can print the Ackermann function without a problem. You have genuine recursion, you just have a stack limit, just like any programming language.

Comment: @okovko I'm going to need to see an actual implementation before I believe that. I really don't see how loops without a known-in-advance iteration count can be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute code in the preprocessor.  You can however create code that generates code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() 
{
    printf("#include <stdio.h>\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("int main()\n");
    printf("{\n");

    srand(time(NULL));
    if (rand() % 2)
        printf("  printf(\"A\");\n");
    else
        printf("  printf(\"B\");\n");

    printf("}\n");
}
```

Output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("A");
}
```

Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("B");
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what we do when we quote syntax in a Lisp macro, right?

Answer (score 0):

To compile based on the result of modulus by two of a random number, we'll need to use [BoostPP](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/mod.hpp>

BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_MOD(RAND, 2), printf("A"); printf("B");)
```

And you'll need to compile using the `-D` option to assign to `RAND` from `/dev/random`, like suggested to you in a comment.

Here are some implementation details of a conditional macro to give you a taste of how it works. The modulus operation requires the implementation of data types and operations on them, which is too long to demonstrate here.

```
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__

#define COMPL(b) PRIMITIVE_CAT(COMPL_, b)
#define COMPL_0 1
#define COMPL_1 0

#define CHECK_N(x, n, ...) n
#define CHECK(...) CHECK_N(__VA_ARGS__, 0,)
#define PROBE(x) x, 1,

#define NOT(x) CHECK(PRIMITIVE_CAT(NOT_, x))
#define NOT_0 PROBE(~)

#define BOOL(x) COMPL(NOT(x))

#define IIF(c) PRIMITIVE_CAT(IIF_, c)
#define IIF_0(t, ...) __VA_ARGS__
#define IIF_1(t, ...) t

#define IF(c) IIF(BOOL(c))

#define EAT(...)
#define EXPAND(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define WHEN(c) IF(c)(EXPAND, EAT)
```

And the usage. Note that `WHEN(0)` does not expand, and any other `WHEN(arg)` will expand.

```
WHEN(0) ( \
  printf("A"); \
)
WHEN(1) ( \
  printf("B"); \
)
WHEN(whatever) ( \
  printf("this will expand too"); \
)
```

Check out [a concise intro to high level CPP](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms) along with the [source for the macros in this example](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/blob/master/cloak.h) for more details on the macros above.